# Add full width colour footer to site - Main wrapper conflicting

Tags: php, css

I'm looking to get a full width footer on my site like this one: http://www.petspyjamas.com/

I seem to have an issue with the main wrapper on my site which affects the whole page and doesn't seem to let me have the footer at full width.

This is my site: http://www.purrfectlyyappy.com/ as you can see the footer area is currently in grey.

Comment: What do you have tried ? Post some code if possible

Answer (score 0):

Your footer is 100% but the innerwrapper is set to 980px

try changing

```
#footer .wrapper { width:100%!important;}
```

as for the color

```
#footer .linebottom {
background: #BDBDBD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to break my HTML pages up into sections (i.e. header, main, footer), and then have containers within each section. That way I can apply background colours/images to sections, and still have the content within constrained to a specific width. Example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <header class="site-header" role="banner">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- branding, navigation etc. -->
      </div>
    </header>
    <section class="site-main" role="main">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- main content -->
      </div>
    </section>
    <footer class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- copyright notice, navigation etc -->
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

So to apply a colour fill to your footer, you can add a simple CSS rule:

```
.site-footer {
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: #333;
}
```